# Non-normalized tables on Entity Framework 6.1

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I got a Many-to-Many relashionship tables but one of them is non-normalized, and i'm getting this error: `The specified association foreign key columns 'FLS_FIL_ID' are invalid. The number of columns specified must match the number of primary key columns.`

The relashionship that i'm trying to do is between File and FlowStep as you can see they are to ICollections, but i got no success.

```
[Table("Controller.TB_FlowStep")]
    public partial class FlowStep : Entity<int>
    {
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string FLS_FLO_ID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int FLS_FIL_ID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int FLS_STE_ID { get; set; }

        public DateTime FLS_TimeStamp { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int FLS_STS_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual Flow Flow { get; set; }

        public virtual Step Step { get; set; }

        public virtual StepStatus StepStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<File> File { get; set; }
    }

[Table("Controller.TB_File")]
public partial class File
{
    [Key]
    public int FIL_Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime FIL_Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string FIL_Type { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    [Required]
    public string FIL_Body { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FIL_SQC { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string FIL_ENV { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FlowStep> FlowStep { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping that i did so far:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<FlowStep>()
            .HasMany(e => e.File)
            .WithMany(e => e.FlowStep)
            .Map(e => 
            {
                e.MapLeftKey("FLS_FIL_ID");
                e.MapRightKey("FIL_ID");
                e.ToTable("TB_FlowStep");
            });
```

Comment: why you need three `Key`s in the first class? Are they also foreignkeys?

Answer (score 0):

`MapLeftKey` takes params string array as all the foreign key names. `MapLeftKey` method's signature is as follows.

```
public ManyToManyAssociationMappingConfiguration MapLeftKey(
    params string[] keyColumnNames
)
```

referenced from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.manytomanyassociationmappingconfiguration.mapleftkey(v=vs.113).aspx) msdn documentation.

try specifying all the keys in `MapLeftKey` method call as following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FlowStep>()
        .HasMany(e => e.File)
        .WithMany(e => e.FlowStep)
        .Map(e => 
        {
            e.MapLeftKey("FLS_FIL_ID","FLS_STE_ID","FLS_STS_ID");
            e.MapRightKey("FIL_ID");
            e.ToTable("TB_FlowStep");
        });
```

Comment: Now i'm getting this error: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: FlowStepFile: Name: The EntitySet 'FlowStepFile' with schema 'Controller' and table 'TB_FlowStep' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.

Comment: @Vinícius You might required to run the migration or delete and recreate a database.

Comment: but i'm not using migrations and i can't drop my database